# How to install Telegram snap on Ubuntu 16.04.2?

Tags: 16.04, snap, telegram

I would install Telegram snap on Ubuntu 16.04.2 and tried with `sudo snap install telegram-sergiusens` but the result was:

```
error: cannot install "telegram-sergiusens": Get
       https://search.apps.ubuntu.com/api/v1/snaps/details/core?channel=stable&fields=anon_download_url%2Carchitecture%2Cchannel%2Cdownload_sha3_384%2Csummary%2Cdescription%2Cdeltas%2Cbinary_filesize%2Cdownload_url%2Cepoch%2Cicon_url%2Clast_updated%2Cpackage_name%2Cprices%2Cpublisher%2Cratings_average%2Crevision%2Cscreenshot_urls%2Csnap_id%2Csupport_url%2Ccontact%2Ctitle%2Ccontent%2Cversion%2Corigin%2Cdeveloper_id%2Cprivate%2Cconfinement%2Cchannel_maps_list:
       dial tcp: lookup search.apps.ubuntu.com on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:55238->[::1]:53: read:
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Weird error. Is snapd up-to-date? What does `snap --version` say?

Comment: @Kyle Thank you!
`snap    2.25
snapd   2.25
series  16
ubuntu  16.04
kernel  4.8.0-53-generic`

Answer (score 0):

Use
 `snap find | grep telegram` 
to search for the Telegram package.

As of the time of writing
 `sudo snap install telegram-desktop` 
will install Telegram.

You may have to reboot in order for it to show up in the application list, however.